# Finding and removing duplicate string constants in multiple files. Reorganize them in a separate file

Tags: java

I am working on an application which has several Java Project files. All project files are using multiple Constant files which has constants with similar values.

For example:

Constant1.java:

---

```
String CONST_NAME1 ="hello"
```

Constant2.java:

---

```
String CONST_NAME2 ="hello"
```

To reduce this redundancy I am looking for an automated approach to  rearrange these constants by identifying and reorganizing duplicate constant values in a single common file and then removing them from all other files.

Any suggestions to achieve the above would be appreciated.

Comment: My advice is to start doing it and when your solution works, look at where the flaky bits are. Then you can ask questions specifically about those areas and how to avoid the problems you encountered. Once you've got the answers to them, throw away ALL the code you'd written up to that point and start again.

Answer (score 0):

I would note down all the constants file you are dealing with and manually merge these into a single file, removing duplicates and leaving the original files untouched. At this point, you should have:

- All the constants in one file
- Not broken any existing code as the original constants files have been left alone

Then, for each constants file:

1. Find the references to it
2. Update these references to use your new constants in the common file
3. Test the changes

Once steps 1 to 3 have been completed for each constants file, you should be safe to delete them from the project.

Comment: Thanks James for your suggestion. Since the volume of files is huge and the duplicate constants are also in hundreds so I am rather looking for an automated approach like a tool or something against doing manually. Indeed thanks for your response.